# How to connect to snowflake using .Net Framework 4.8 (not Core) with Authenticator=ExternalBrowser

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get my app built in .Net Framework 4.8 link to Snowflake for data source. I don't have user and password to get into snowflake as it's generally logged in automatically with our corporate Windows credential. My Snowflake admin said I can simply use Authenticator=ExternalBrowser. I used it in my connection string but it didn't work.

How to connect to Snowflake using .net framework 4.8?

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I'm on the same boat right now

Comment: @jegtugado no, did you find a way?

Comment: I've targeted 4.7.2 which is the only version that works with the [snowflake .net connector](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net)

Comment: Thanks that's a helpful start.